# How to check if two elements are visible jquery?

Tags: jquery, element, operator-keyword, visible

How do I check if two elements are visible, I tried like this below, but it doesn't work.. Why?
I've tried this. But it doesn't work, how is the right way to set it up?

```
if($("#about")&&("#info").is(":visible")){
//Some action here
}
```

Comment: You can't abbreviate chaining that way. `if($("#about").is(":visible") && $("#info").is(":visible")){ ...`

Comment: why the `$("#about")` in the if clause?

Comment: Another possibility: `$('#about:visible,#info:visible').length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$("#about")` returns an object, which is considered true by `if` statement. Instead use this:

```
if( $("#about").is(":visible") && $("#info").is(":visible") ) {
  //Some action here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you missed small thing

```
if($("#about").is(":visible")&&$("#info").is(":visible")){
//Some action here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the selectors into a single statement:

```
if($('#about,#info').is(':visible')) {
     // when both are visible
}
```

Comment: This will check if at least one of them is visible. The question was about checking if *both* are visible. http://jsfiddle.net/eVa8w/